# Simply JQuery math syntax- how do I subtract?

Tags: jquery, math, subtraction

Hello wonderful community,

I am trying to do some really simple math with JQuery, but I can't find a cheatsheat with math syntax on it (that is relevant to what I'm trying to do). I know how to do additions & multiplication but subtraction is eluding me!

What I need to do is assign a style to "#photo" that has a value of (total width of viewport - (241px + (height*0.32))). This code is successfully grabbing the total width of the viewport and assigning it as the width of #photo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $(window).width(); 
    $('#photo').css('width', width);
});
```

But nothing I've tried by way of ('width', (width- (value + value))) has worked - can someone let me know what the syntax is for subtraction and nested equations?

OR, rather than calculate (height*0.32) again, how would I assign the output of (height*0.32) to a var so I can re-use it, making the width calculation something like ('width', (width- (281px - varname)))?

Here's the whole function including the (height*0.32) calc:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width(); 
    $('#menu').css('height', height);
    $('#menu').css('width', (height*0.29));
    $('#menu').css('position','fixed');
    $('#menu').removeClass('nojavascript');
    $('#novel').css('padding-left', (height*0.32));
    $('#novel').removeClass('nojavascript');
    $('#photo').css('width', width);
});
```

Er, further tips on how to tidy my code also appreciated. Just looking at it I can guess at some things that might well be unnecessary duplications!

Edited per request: 
Here is the subtraction problem, which I've got working now:

```
  $('img').css('width', (width - (281+(height*0.32))) + 'px');
```

Now the problem I'm wrestling with is how to calculate a height for img so that it preserves a 4:3 photo ratio! But it's nearly 4am so that will have to wait til morning.

Comment: could you post the subtraction problem as it appears in your code, so we could see it?

Answer (score 2):

For formatting, a few things.  jQuery can take objects for CSS, so pass everything in, in a single go.  Secondly, only when the key isn't a valid javascript identifier (see "padding-left") do you need quotes around it.  Third, jQuery objects chain, so you can follow the `css()` call with the `removeclass()` call in-line.  And finally, indenting is really, *really* your friend.

And finally, the `height` and `width` functions return bare integers, but the `css()` function requires that you include units.  The most fundamental unit, and the one returned by `height` and `width`, is pixels:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = $(window).height(), width = $(window).width();
    $('#menu').css({height: height + 'px', width: (height * 0.29) + 'px', position: 'fixed'})
        .removeClass('nojavascript');
    $('#novel').css({'padding-left': (height * 0.32) + 'px'})
        .removeClass('nojavascript');
    $('#photo').css({width: width + 'px'});
 });
```

Comment: That was my answer too, but I just tested it out on SO (jQuery 1.5.2) and it looks like jQuery is smart enough to a) convert bare numbers to `num + 'px'` and b) `Math.floor()` floats. But that behavior might be browser-specific.

Comment: Would it be browser-specific then that the block I put in my post works perfectly to assign widths and heights where they need to go, with pixels assigned? For instance, #menu gets style="height: 583px; width: 169.07px; position: fixed; " even if I don't + 'px' in the code.

Comment: And thanks for the formatting tips, it's really helpful to see them laid out against actual code I'm using rather than in abstract.

Comment: `...but the css() function requires that you include units.` This is simply not true. While you have to provide a unit of measure in your CSS, jQuery is smart enough to add it in for you...